# Symfony Serializer cannot handle Doctrine Id on deserialize

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

I am trying to serialize and then deserialize a Doctrine Entity in Symfony 3. Well it does not work for the `id` property of course because there's no public accessor to the `id` by default. So what's the best option for that?

1. Add a `setId()` method, but that's probably a bad idea and
   undermines the doctrine default behaviour.
2. Use a custom `Normalizer` that uses reflection to construct the
   object by just accessing the field.
3. Give the entity some custom `toArray()`, `fromArray()` functionality and use the array values instead of the object in the serialization.

Or am i missing something? Is there already something build into symfony for that usecase?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `object_to_populate` option to do that :

```
    // retrieve entity to update from DB
    $oldProduct = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Product::class)->find($request->request->get('id'));

    $product = $this->get('serializer')->deserialize($request->getContent(), Product::class, 'json', array('object_to_populate' => $oldProduct));

    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entityManager->persist($product);
    $entityManager->flush();
```

See [Deserializing in an Existing Object documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.0/components/serializer.html#deserializing-in-an-existing-object)